# ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis oracle error probably because I messed up the syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, create-table

So this is a table I am trying to create in relation to another table in my database. I know I have messed up the syntax somewhere, I'm just not sure where because oracle doesn't point out the exact line of error. Any help will be appreciated. And yes I'm new to this

```sql
CREATE TABLE USERS (
    USER_ID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(255), 
    YEAR_OF_BIRTH YEAR, 
    SEX CHAR(2), 
    ADDRESS VARCHAR2(255), 
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20), 
    CA_ID NUMBER(5),
    FOREIGN KEY CA_ID REFERENCES CANDIDATE(CANDIDATE_ID) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK.

Comment: Did you try to delete all the fields except name and see if that works?  Then add in fields until you can isolate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

- Change `YEAR_OF_BIRTH YEAR` to have a valid data type as `YEAR` is not a valid data type.
- Have braces around the column(s) you are declaring the foreign key on.
- `ON DELETE NO ACTION` is not [syntactically correct](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE). You cannot take no action if the item being referenced is deleted as then the constraint will be violated; instead you need to either set the value to `NULL` or delete the record using `CASCADE` or omit the `ON DELETE` clause if you do not want the parent record to be able to be deleted if this child exists and references the parent.

Like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE USERS (
  USER_ID       NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME          VARCHAR2(255), 
  YEAR_OF_BIRTH NUMBER(4), 
  SEX           CHAR(2), 
  ADDRESS       VARCHAR2(255), 
  PHONE_NUMBER  VARCHAR2(20), 
  CA_ID         NUMBER(5),
  FOREIGN KEY ( CA_ID ) REFERENCES CANDIDATE(CANDIDATE_ID ) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=180be9687505bcb3fc98cfb4090a0922)

Comment: YEAR_OF_BIRTH really should be a DATE, not a NUMBER.  Even if all the app is interested in is the year, by declaring it a DATE, you avoid the possibility of having invalid values.  I don't know anyone who was born in the year 0000 or 9999, but keeping the year as a NUMBER, you miss having the database enforce valid values.

Comment: Well, @EdS, that would probably be year 0, not 0000 (`number` datatype, eh?) :)

Comment: @Littlefoot - (blush)   :-)